# Linking Server Side Message/Exception with AJAX request

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, exception, glassfish, primefaces

I am making an ajax submit using Primefaces but I am having trouble linking my server side message with my ajax request.
Supposed I have this button that calls an action.

In my managed bean, do I need to raise an exception?  How do I pass this message into my ajax request

```
public void checkout(ActionEvent event){
    if(expression){
        throw new CustomException("Account balance is not enough!");
    }
}

public class CustomException extends RuntimeException { 
    public CustomException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

How do I handle this case? Will my onerror javascript method be able to handle this?

Also, in one case supposed DB is down then how do I handle the exception?  Do I have accessed to the error message
in my javascript function?

```
public void checkout(ActionEvent event){
    try{
        //DB is down
        if(expression){
            throw new CustomException("Account balance is not enough!");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As to your concrete question, you need to implement a custom [`ExceptionHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExceptionHandler.html) for this which does *basically* the following when an exception occurs in an ajax request:

```
String errorPageLocation = "/WEB-INF/errorpages/500.xhtml";
context.setViewRoot(context.getApplication().getViewHandler().createView(context, errorPageLocation));
context.getPartialViewContext().setRenderAll(true);
context.renderResponse();
```

This is not exactly trivial if you want to take `web.xml` error pages into account. You'd need to parse the entire `web.xml` for this to find the error page locations. The [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) utility library has exactly such an exception handler, the [`FullAjaxExceptionHandler`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/exceptionhandler/FullAjaxExceptionHandler.html). You can find the full source code [here](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/master/src/org/omnifaces/exceptionhandler/FullAjaxExceptionHandler.java) and the showcase example [here](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler).

As to your concrete functional requirement, I wouldn't throw an exception when there's just an user error. This is fully recoverable. You need to create and add a `FacesMessage` and have ajax to update the `<h:messages>`, `<p:messages>` or `<p:growl>`. The PrimeFaces ones support an `autoUpdate="true"` which would auto-update itself on ajax requests. E.g.

```
context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Insufficient balance", null));
```

with

```html
<p:messages autoUpdate="true" />
```

Throwing an exception makes only sense in unrecoverable situations like as when the DB is down. Note that you usually don't throw such an exception *yourself*. In case of JPA it would already be thrown as `PersistenceException` which you in turn shouldn't catch in JSF managed bean, but just let it go.

Comment: Why do you know so much stuff? Err..Just Kidding.  Thanks always... :)